# Excel data filter/sort

Tags: excel, where-clause, ifs

I have a problem sorting/filter out the data I want. It is a huge document with thousands and thousands of rows.

I need to match the columns `nr` and `flag`. I need to find the rows where these conditions are met:

So I want to find all rows, for all "nr" where they only appear as 11E*** in the flag column and never as 11A*** and/or 11C***..... So there has to be a check for every nr so to speak.

[image]

I hope you understand what I want to do here. I just can´t figure out how to make this in a good way as I´ve tried nested ifs and got stuck.

Comment: Can't you just put a filter filters all the values in **flag** where **flag** starts with "11E"? This should be under text filters.

Comment: So you say "11E***" **and never** as "11A***" or "11C***". I saw you making a comment and then perhaps deleting. So based on your description I think filter will work

Comment: How can I filter so that I check in "nr" for the ones where "flag" only contains 11E (may have one or more 11E) and not 11A or 11C. Since the numbers that conatain 11E and 11A or 11C are not of interest.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide an example of the desired output because I don't seem to understand what you want to check in column "nr"